# App running in a pod of AKS cluster can't access VM from the same resource group

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster in `dev-test` resource group on Azure. One of the services running there - `api-service` needs to connect to a service running on a VM outside the cluster, in the same resource group - let's call that `elk-vm`.

The `api-service` app takes some configmap that has the address of `elk-vm`. No matter how I state the address (public IP, DNS name or VM name), the connection gets timed out. The `elk-vm` is accessible from other VMs in `dev-test` but this doesn't seem to apply to AKS nodes.

I guess my problem is lack of understanding how to properly configure AKS networking for that. From the Azure docs I understood that as long as those two were in the same resource group (`dev-test`) they should be able to see each other.

I've tried to use public IP of the `elk-VM` in the config so that `api-service` can call it even if they're not in the same virtual network but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there seems to be no way of adding an existing AKS cluster to a virtual network the same way that the "Bring Your Own Virtual Network" option does when creating the cluster.

Since the BYOVN is only available when creating a cluster I needed to create a new one with this setting: `--vnet-subnet-id $SUBNET_ID`, where `$SUBNET_ID` was from the virtual network I wanted to connect in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It could depend how AKS is set up: basic or advanced (CNI) networking configuration. In the CNI mode, pods get an IP from the subnet, which simplifies communication with other resources in the same VNet

Comment: It's set to CNI mode but I can't see which subnet are the pods in. I would expect to see it in 'Networking' tab in the cluster but it's not there.